# Is it possible to download a Google Drive folder as a .zip?

Tags: google-drive, file-conversion

I've seen that this is possible in Google+.

How can I do this?

Comment: Follow up question: Is there a way to generate a permanent link which downloads a folder as a zip?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Downloading as zip archive is the default behavior for multiple file download in Google Drive.

1. Select multiple files and/or folders
2. Right click selection and choose `Download...`
   [image]
3. In windows that appears, review your selection and click Download...
   [image]
4. Wait for the progress to finish
   [image]
5. Your download will start automatically (if it does not - click the link)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What will happen when there are hundreds of files in that folder? I read that there is a limit to the size of the zip and the number of files. What if it is bigger, will it split into multiple downloads?

Comment: You can download up to 2GB at a time. This is the limit. AFAIK, everything below 2GB will come in a single ZIP archive. Anything above 2GB just won't download. I dot not have enough files to check the upper limit though.

Comment: I shared a folder with a friend through a link. He does not have to sign in to see the folder content. But he cannot select multiple files, he can only download files one by one. So this advice works only for users signed in.

Answer (score 0):

To download the Ara or Rar file from google drive open all sub folder and right click choose download after all download one pop up will come choose "leave" it gets download.